# Facebook 403 Error

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm able to access the Facebook graph API with my app but after a certain point, I get the dreaded "403 Forbidden #4" error returned in the response header. I get the error whether I call the URL through my app, or just enter it in the browser directly. I know for a fact that I'm not exceeding the 600 calls in 600 seconds limit by utilizing WAS7 caching (I'll make a new, direct call every 5 minutes, or 2 calls every 600 seconds).

What's more frustrating is that the 403 error "locks me out" for a good long time (maybe 6-10 hours). Once I wait this amount of time, I'm able to fetch the data as if nothing happened both in my application, and through the browser. I guess my question is, does Facebook keep some sort of longer tally of Graph calls? Maybe over the span of a day? And does it kick you out from accessing the API if you go over this amount? Let me know if I'm being too ambiguous or confusing as I'd be happy to clarify. Thanks!

For reference, the URL I'm using is as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/POSTID/?fields=caption,full_picture,description,id,message,name,type,link

Comment: you should always use an access token for api calls.

Comment: I'm utilizing Facebook4J, and with that, I'm using the concatenated "ID|Secret" token. Authentication doesn't seem to be the issue. It's telling me that I've reached a call limit.

Comment: that´s an app access token, you should try to avoid using those. there is only one per app, so you can reach the limit very fast.

Comment: Wouldn't my caching approach account for that? I essentially have the app checking the cache before moving on to make a fresh call, which is only once every five minutes.

Comment: if you only do one call every 5min, you should not reach any limit with the app token. btw, that "600 calls in 600 seconds" is not a static rule, it´s just a guideline.

Comment: First of all, you should check what error message the API returns.